# General Linking for Android NDK Makefile, Android.mk and OCaml

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk, ocaml

I am using the Android NDK kit and have this Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ocaml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ocaml/hello.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# ocamlfind -toolchain android ocamlopt \
# -output-complete-obj -cclib -shared hello.ml -o hello.so

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := simple_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
# This name had to be that created shared library
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := ocaml
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/gar/.opam/android_coding/lib/ocaml

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

This compiles successfully and creates in `/home/gar/ocaml_on_android/libs/armeabi` simple_test and hello.so.

However when I run the code on my Nexus 7, I get

`CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: library "/home/gar/ocaml_on_android/obj/local/armeabi/hello.so" not found`

Which means its not linking correctly at compile time. How can I write this Android.mk file so that everything compiles statically in one executable ?

EDIT: 
After comments, using this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ocaml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ocaml/hello.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# ocamlfind -toolchain android ocamlopt \
# -output-complete-obj -cclib -shared hello.ml -o hello.so

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := simple_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrapper.c
# This name had to be that created shared library
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := hello.so
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/gar/.opam/android_coding/lib/ocaml

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

and in my `libs` folder of the project I still have two objects, the hello.so and the simple_test exectuable, I expected to see just one. And for the `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`, not sure if I need to put the module name, ocaml, or the actual shared object, the hello.so. Either case still produced two objects in the libs directory.

EDIT2: I now have this for my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ocaml
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ocaml/hello.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# ocamlfind -toolchain android ocamlopt \
# -output-complete-obj -cclib -shared hello.ml -o hello.so

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := simple_test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := wrapper.c
# This name had to be that created shared library
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wl,-Bstatic -static
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := hello ocaml
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/gar/.opam/android_coding/lib/ocaml

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

And when I check the created executable, I still see that its depending on the shared library

```
arm-linux-androideabi-readelf -d simple_test | grep NEEDED
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [/home/gar/asm_on_android/obj/local/armeabi/hello.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
```

I also tried the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./simple_test` command on the shell on the device but got this error:

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH= . ./simple_test                                                                 
sh: ./simple_test[1]: syntax error: '\
                                       4' unexpected
```

Comment: I don't see any `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` when you build your executable.

Comment: @Michael Tried that and updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to Alex for his help.

I've decided to skip Android-NDK for now and just went for a straight Makefile solution, which does work.

Here's the Makefile

```
cc := arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

sys_root := /Users/Edgar/.opam/4.02.3+32bit/lib/android-ndk/platforms/android-21/arch-arm

includes := /Users/Edgar/.opam/4.02.3+32bit/arm-linux-androideabi/include

ml_includes := /Users/Edgar/.opam/4.02.3+32bit/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/ocaml/

libs := /Users/Edgar/.opam/4.02.3+32bit/arm-linux-androideabi/lib

# Be sure to do export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. and then run the program.
# Not sure how to do static linking yet, this will only dynamically
# link the program
complete: lib
    $(cc) --sysroot $(sys_root) -I$(includes) -L$(libs) \
    -pie -I$(ml_includes) hello.so main.c -o Finished

lib:
    ocamlfind -toolchain android ocamlopt -output-complete-obj \
    -cclib '-lm -shared' hello.ml -o hello.so

# This is a pure OCaml exectuable
exec:
    ocamlfind -toolchain android ocamlopt \
    -verbose -ccopt '-fPIE' -cclib '-pie' hello.ml -o hello

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf *.{cmi,cmt,o,cmx,so} Finished
```

...Substitute your names and paths as appropriate. 
Also put the repo up here, https://github.com/fxfactorial/ocaml_on_android

Answer (score 1):

This is how shared libraries are used. You can push `hello.so` to your device near the `simple_test` executable.

The syntax for **Android.mk** should be

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := ocaml
```

On shell command line, use

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./simple_test
```

Comment: I see, can you also provide a complete example for statically linking everything?

Comment: added more details/problems/examples.

Comment: To build a statically-linked ocaml app, follow http://komar.bitcheese.net/en/howto_link_c_lib_statically_with_ocaml_app. At any rate, `-Bstatic` is not of much help for you here; it cannot magically convert your **hello.so** to static library.

Comment: At any rate, the syntax error is because you had a space between `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` and `.`.